# Unable to edit a query's results using multiple table references and "group by"

Tags: ms-access

I have a continuous form that displays a set of time ranges and an ID, that currently looks like:

```
T1     T2     ID
----------------
09:00  09:15  1
09:15  09:30  2
09:25  09:50  3
09:50  10:20  4
```

Each ID is unique to the row. My goal was to highlight any times that were clashing (in this example the rows with ID 2 and 3 clash since 3 starts before 2 has ended). I decided to do this using conditional formatting, so wanted a field in each row to indicate whether there was a clash present.

I achieved this by using a query that referenced the dataset twice, allowing me to compare the rows to each other:

```
[a].[T1]<[b].[T2] And [a].[T2]>[b].[T1] And [a].[ID]<>[b].[ID]
```

Assigning this as a field to a query gave me something like this:

```
a.T1    a.T2   a.ID  b.ID  Clash  
--------------------------------
09:00   09:15  1     1     False
09:00   09:15  1     2     False
09:00   09:15  1     3     False
09:00   09:15  1     4     False
09:15   09:30  2     1     False
09:15   09:30  2     2     False
09:15   09:30  2     3     True
09:15   09:30  2     4     False
09:25   09:50  3     1     False
09:25   09:50  3     2     True
09:25   09:50  3     3     False
09:25   09:50  3     4     False
09:50   10:20  4     1     False
09:50   10:20  4     2     False
09:50   10:20  4     3     False
09:50   10:20  4     4     False
```

And to remove all duplicates I used **group by** on the **a.ID** field and took the **Max** of the calculated field (0 or -1) so I got True, if it was ever present per **a.ID**. This gave me:

```
a.T1   a.T2   a.ID  Clash
-------------------------
09:00  09:15  1     False
09:15  09:30  2     True
09:25  09:50  3     True
09:50  10:20  4     False
```

Almost perfect, however, due to this new calculated field, and the fact I am essentially grouping results, I am no longer able to edit Time1 or Time2 when viewing this final result in a continuous form view.

Is there a way I can still edit the time fields and keep this new calculated field? Or maybe a separate way of handling clashes that allow me to provide visual feedback in the form view?

I realise there is a lot here and I may not have explained something clearly, if this is the case please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Good catch HansUp, I actually made a typo there, I have fixed it now. The second part should be
    `[a].[T2]>=[b].[T1]`

Comment: Does ID 1 (09:00 - 09:15) qualify as a clash with ID 2 (09:15 - 09:30)?  That pair satisfies the revised condition in your question, but your expected output shows Clash = False for ID 1.

Comment: That's what I get for not copying straight from my own data and just making it up as I wrote the question. You are right again, in order for my example to be valid I should be using `>` and `<` instead of `>=` and `<=`. I didn't initially double check the conditional expression used as it's not too pertinent to the problem I was facing, but I have updated the original question for any future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I tackled it: I started with a query quite similar to your original one, except that I used an INNER JOIN to reduce the number of raw results returned

```
SELECT a.ID, a.T1, a.T2, b.ID, b.T1, b.T2,
    a.T2 > b.T1 AS Clash
FROM TimeSlots a INNER JOIN TimeSlots b ON b.ID > a.ID;
```

That query returned

```
a.ID  a.T1      a.T2      b.ID  b.T1      b.T2      Clash
----  --------  --------  ----  --------  --------  -----
   1  09:00:00  09:15:00     2  09:15:00  09:30:00      0
   1  09:00:00  09:15:00     3  09:25:00  09:50:00      0
   2  09:15:00  09:30:00     3  09:25:00  09:50:00     -1
   1  09:00:00  09:15:00     4  09:50:00  10:20:00      0
   2  09:15:00  09:30:00     4  09:50:00  10:20:00      0
   3  09:25:00  09:50:00     4  09:50:00  10:20:00      0
```

I took your cue and did a GROUP BY, except that I did MIN() and kept the boolean values as numbers...

```
SELECT First(a.T1) AS T1, First(a.T2) AS T2, a.ID,
    MIN(a.T2 > b.T1) AS Clash
FROM TimeSlots a INNER JOIN TimeSlots b ON b.ID > a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID;
```

...which returned...

```
T1        T2        ID  Clash
--------  --------  --  -----
09:00:00  09:15:00   1      0
09:15:00  09:30:00   2     -1
09:25:00  09:50:00   3      0
```

Then I noticed that ID=4 was missing, so for completeness I added it back in...

```
SELECT First(a.T1) AS T1, First(a.T2) AS T2, a.ID,
    MIN(a.T2 > b.T1) AS Clash
FROM TimeSlots a INNER JOIN TimeSlots b ON b.ID > a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT T1, T2, ID, 0 AS Clash 
FROM TimeSlots WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TimeSlots);
```

...so I got...

```
T1        T2        ID  Clash
--------  --------  --  -----
09:00:00  09:15:00   1      0
09:15:00  09:30:00   2     -1
09:25:00  09:50:00   3      0
09:50:00  10:20:00   4      0
```

Now the tricky bit. That query is not updateable, and (from my limited testing) neither is any query that JOINs to it, or uses it directly in a subquery.

However, if I save that query as [ClashList] and use it along with the VBA Function...

```
Public Function GetClashStatus(ID As Long) As Long
GetClashStatus = DLookup("Clash", "ClashList", "ID=" & ID)
End Function
```

...I can create this query...

```
SELECT TimeSlots.T1, TimeSlots.T2, TimeSlots.ID, GetClashStatus(TimeSlots.ID) AS Clash
FROM TimeSlots;
```

...and it *is* updateable.

### Edit

As it turns out, the VBA Function is not required. This works, too:

```
SELECT TimeSlots.T1, TimeSlots.T2, TimeSlots.ID, 
    DLookup("Clash", "ClashList", "ID=" & ID) AS Clash
FROM TimeSlots;
```

Comment: Thank you Gord for this answer, I replied to coge.soft with a similar solution but it wasn't explained as well as this one. It seems to work perfectly so far (apart from graphical glitches with conditional formatting not showing, but that's a separate issue).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not able to be updated because of the `GROUP BY`.  Access doesn't know which record(s) to change.  If any table or query is not updateable and used in a `JOIN` in another query, this second query will also not be updateable.

Source: [Allen Browne, "Why is my query read-only?"](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

I'm sure there is a better way, but I know `INSERT`ing your `GROUP BY` into a new, temporary table would work.  You could then join your table of grouped data to your real data.  With both recordsets being updateable, your query would be, as well.

Comment: I actually used this idea for the final solution. I used a second query that didn't calculate the clash column. Instead, it uses dlookup to get the clash value from the uneditable query.

Comment: Yes, since the second query did not need to calculate the clash column, it didn't need to refer to the original table twice. I therefore didn't need to group any records, and could read the clashes (using dlookup) from the previously grouped query.

Comment: Right...  because `DLookup()` is read-only.  Was my answer at least somewhat useful?

Comment: I guess the clash field is never really editable, but since it's a purely calculated field, I wouldn't want expect it to ever be editable. Your answer was useful yes, thank you! It made me realise I wasn't going to be able to make the original query editable, so I looked for ways to bring the non-editable data into an editable recordset.